# How To Build a DRY Image Gallery - in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been tinkering with a small image gallery for my project for a few days now, but I feel that I'm not going about it in a very pythonic manner thus far in terms of this part of the project.

A lot of questions have risen during the tinkering, alas being new to python and django I cannot immediately see how I ought to go about improving what I'd like to improve in the code.

Here's the user profile model; I reckon it will sort of jump at you what I mean:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_visible = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = RichTextUploadingField(
                                external_plugin_resources=[(
                                    'youtube',
                                    '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
                                    'plugin.js'
                                    )],
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True,
                                )
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    reddit = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    youtube = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    linkdin = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    img_1 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_2 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_3 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_4 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_5 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_6 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_7 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_8 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    img_9 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images')

    def __str__(self):
        # return 'kartofler'
        return self.user.username
        # return f'{self.user.username} profile'

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        super().save()
        # this part needs expansion.
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.width > 300 or img.height > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

        #EXPERIMENT: THUMBNAIL MACHINE
        img_1 = Image.open(self.img_1.path)
        xpad = int(img_1.width/2)-45
        ypad = int(img_1.height/2)-45
        coords = (xpad, ypad, xpad+90, ypad+90)
        crop_img = img_1.crop(coords)
        crop_img.save(self.img_1.path)  # should save to a (colored) thumbnail folder in stead.
        crop_img = ImageOps.grayscale(crop_img)
        crop_img.save(self.img_1.path)  # should save to a (b/w) thumbnail folder in stead.
```

First off, there's clearly something iffy going on with the 9 imagefields at the bottom. It's not DRY and also what I'm trying to do in the bottom half of the def save() strikes me as problematic in light of the aforementioned 9 fields, as it strikes me that I'm creating a rather ugly monster. I'd like to iterate over those imagefields in stead of repeating myself or something similar.

The forms.py file connected to this model is equally "WET". The template which displays it all is obviously equally redundant in it's ways.

Also I'm confused as to how to create (and delete) subfolders in the media folder. I tried to do a cheeky string with a template variable and a raw string, but to no avail.
It would be very nice if I could create some sort of hierachy based off the usernames (and perhaps a timestamp).

Basically I'm asking for directions. If you happen to know of some good resources that I could read (or watch, it doesn't matter which), I'd be much obliged. If you've got a killer idea, this is obviously equally welcome.

Thank you kindly for reading along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create another model for user photos.

```
import datetime
def upload_file(instance, filename):
    # you can add datetime
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # image/users/{username}/{now}/{filename}
    return os.path.join('users/%s/' % instance.profile.user.username, now, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_visible = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = RichTextUploadingField(
                            external_plugin_resources=[(
                                'youtube',
                                '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
                                'plugin.js'
                                )],
                                blank=True,
                                null=True,
                            )
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    reddit = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    youtube = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    linkdin = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

class Profile_Photo(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey("Profile", related_name="photos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_file)

#You can access user photos like this
# user = request.user
# profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
# photos = profile.photos.all()
```

Comment: I woke up this morning with the same idea, and I realised how I could probably just have a single field and then load that 9 times, somehow. 

Thank you all the same, and dare I say: I really like how you put that comment in there at the bottom. Everyone ought to add those in, cheers :)